# Q: HighChart view Table(fn: getTable) be behind in one's columns

Tags: javascript, highcharts

get the data from DB and spread the date(YYYY-MM) on xAxis.
And it can see the table just below the chart through the getTable() function,
there is a shape where one more data in the table is generated and pushed back.
For example, it starts from 2020-08, and as it starts from 2020-07 in the table, the data is pushed back one by one on a date basis.
In the chart, it was confirmed that it normally started at 2020-08.
What's the problem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi @YoungJoon, Please reproduce the problem in some online code editor by using mocked data with the same format as yours. You can use this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1fuLmgk6/ as a base to start.

Comment: Thank you, @ppotaczek. But I think it's okay because I've already solved the problem. Thank you for your comment.